# Selecting parents slements in DOM in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-selectors

I have DIV wrapper which I want to toogle class using children element. However the DOM three isn't the best:

```
<div class="wrapper-I-want-to-toogle-class">
   <div class="other-class">
      <div class="other-class">
         <span class="element-I-want-to-triggle-toogle-class">X</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to do that?
I have alredy tried to use:

```
$(this).parents(".wrapper").classList.toogle('active');
```

However wordpress does not really allow to use functions like that.
Can You help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, its important to select the correct class name of the parent, and the child used to toggle the parent

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.target').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parents(".wrapper").toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  background:#CCC;
}
.wrapper.active{
  height:150px;
}
.target {
 float:right;
 display:flex;
 background:#EEE;
 color:#666;
 border:1px solid #aaa;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:middel;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="other-class">
      <div class="other-class">
         <span class="target">X</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. The problem was I didn't known I only can use jQuerry functions in this wrapping function. But I've found out that wordpress block jQuerry without that.

Comment: Since it is wordpress you need to replace the `$` with `jQuery` as by default wordpress disables the shorthand for jQuery